# Docker-Compose Up Works but Eb Local Run does not

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-compose, dockerfile

Attached is my docker-compose file.  Its a very simple project with a database and phpmyadmin to access it.

```
web:
    build: ./docker_web/
    links:
        - db
    ports: 
        - "80:80"
    volumes: 
        - "./docker_web/www/:/var/www/site"
db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ^^^^
      MYSQL_DATABASE: electionbattle
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ^^^^
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8081:80
    volumes:
     - /sessions
    links:
        - db
```

If I run this it works fine.  I created the equivlent for Amazon Docker Run for Elastic Beanstalk and it starts up but for some reason it can't find the volume that is holding my persisted database data in the .data folder.

I've tried changing .data to just data no luck.

Also I get a weird error when trying to do `eb deploy`

```
2016-09-24 19:56:10 UTC-0700    ERROR   ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (db: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (500): create ./.data/db/: "./.data/db/" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed web: phpmyadmin: )
```

I have no idea how to fix this error or why its happening.  Any ideas?

Oops forgot to add my amazon file :).

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "./docker_web/www/"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "db",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "./data/db/"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "197984628663.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/electionbattleonline",
      "memory": 200,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "web",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/site",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "db",
      "image": "mysql:latest",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "^^^^"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
          "value": "electionbattleonline"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_USER",
          "value": "admin"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
          "value": "^^^^"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 3306,
        "containerPort": 3306
      }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "db",
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 200
    },
    {
      "name": "phpmyadmin",
      "image": "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "PMA_ARBITRARY",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8081,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this the whole compose file above? Aren't you using `version: "2"` ?

Comment: yes its the whole file, docker-compose and its counter part the Dockerrun.aws.json

Comment: interestingly enough I got rid of the db container and it gives the same error now for the web container when I try to deploy? how strange... does it not like mounting volumes?

Comment: I suggest you use the current version of docker, with its docker-compose format. The non version 2 is getting quite outdated now. See this https://docs.docker.com/compose/. You don't need `links:` anymore. Also post your `docker info` '`docker version`.

Comment: can you elaborate on the non version 2? Does this pertain to Amazon's docker run?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use relative paths.

Use **eb local run** to test before deploying, it will help you solve deployment issues. Your *Dockerrun.aws.json* file will be converted into a *docker-compose.yml* file and started using a local copy of docker.

You can find the generated docker-compose.yml in your project directory at the path *.elasticbeanstalk/docker-compose.yml*. You will notice that your volumes are missing from the docker-compose config file.

To fix this change your volumes to:

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "web",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/docker_web/www/"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "db",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/data/db/"
    }
  }
],
```

and create the directories in your app, then "eb local run" will correctly convert them.

eb deploy should now work correctly.

Comment: I will give this a try, been stuck on this all this time.